# Parsing a string prints garbage

Tags: c

I have this problem parsing a string. I am not from a C field.

I have this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char DataIn[65] = "WV,000B,404C494748543B.";

int main()
{
    char *p = DataIn;

    puts(DataIn);
            
    for (int count = 0;count<2 ; ++count) {
        p = strstr(p, ",");
        if (!p )
            break;
        p++;            
    }
            
    char *endPointer = strchr(p, '.');
    *endPointer = '\0';
            
    puts(p);
}
```

The output I want from this example is: `404C494748543B` (which can have different length).

When I print `p` , **usually** its ok, but sometimes, **only once in a while**, I get this :

```
404C494748543B
X
@LIGHT;
��
@LIGHT;

    ��03
```

Which includes some previous data + garbage .

Is there something wrong with the way I extract the data ?

Comment: Which input produces garbage?

Comment: Why don't you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: `p = strstr(p, ",");` --> `p = strstr(prev, ",");` ... print prev.

Comment: @EdgarRokyan thanks, as I wrote, when I print p at the end I get the garbage.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thanks, but I am not sure I got you.

Comment: I say [like this](http://ideone.com/M6yWvL)

Comment: Your code will only work if your data is in the exact format that you expect it to be.  If you receive something even slightly out of what you expect, your code will blow up spectacularly.

Comment: In any case, if we *assume* that your input is as you expect it to be, then the code that you show us would not be producing the output that you show us.  Which means that either your inputs are not what you are saying they are, or the way you print your output has problems.  And we cannot know, because you have not shown us either.

Comment: So, ***how about posting a complete question,*** in the form of a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, AND showing us the exact input you are using?

Comment: @MikeCAT I tried to edit it into a form which should be compileable, hopefully preserving the gist of the question.

Comment: @MikeNakis I am sorry if its not in the regular form, but its a part of a large embedded program. I can definitely tell that his code will provide the right result most of the time, with the input looks exactly as I showed here. Anyway, thanks, I will go do some homework.

Comment: @Curnelious okay, thanks for the code, now you can also find it here: http://ideone.com/UaQbWD and as you might guess, it never fails. So, in this sense it is not really an mcve, because it does not reproduce the problem.  So, you need to keep adding stuff to it until the problem becomes reproducible.   And I am willing to bet that the moment you add that little something that will cause it to start failing, you will immediately know what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When things work most of the time, but sometimes you get garbage, it is undefined behavior. This means that `DataIn` points to invalid memory - something that has been de-allocated, or is allocated on the stack of a function that has finished working.

The best way to diagnose and fix this problem is to run your code through a memory profiler, such as [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

**Note:** There are two situations when your loop ends:

- `count` reaches 2 (normal exit), or
- `p` is set to `NULL` (on a break)

The code searching for `endPointer`, however, assumes that `p` is not `NULL` without any checks, which means your program may crash when the loop exits on a `break`.

Comment: Thanks I know I have to check for p, but at the time I get the crash I can see that DataIn is valid, and have all the characters I am searching for.

Comment: @Curnelious Run with valgrind, it will point to the problem right away, even if the code does not print garbage.

Comment: Well this code is on a chip, so I do not have all the available tools. But can you explain how is that possible that DataIn is valid and I will search for the comma and not find it? I can print it and see that its valid (?)

Comment: @Curnelious That's the thing, you cannot ensure that `DataIn` is valid simply by printing it. The memory may be freed, or released through the stack, but still have the old data that looks correct when printed. Can you memory profile the code outside your target system?

Comment: Yes. Ok I see. I will check it in depth. thank you .